# EventSource not working in angular 6 due to module http and https

Tags: angular, eventsource

I am using an EventSource in my angular 6 project. When I try to run my project using `ng serve`, I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/eventsource/lib/eventsource.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in
>   '${MY_PATH}/node_modules/eventsource/lib'

This error appears the same for '**https**' module. I tried to use the `HttpClientModule` instead of the `HttpModule` but it didn't work. I also tried to install the `EventSource` explicitly by running `npm install eventsource`, but the issue is still there.

The code that I'm using:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as EventSource from 'eventsource';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    private eventSource: EventSource;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.eventSource = new EventSource('/subscribe');
        this.eventSource.reconnectInterval = 1;
    }

    // Rest of the code omitted for clarity
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's a closed issue for this on their GitHub https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource/issues/99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using this [event source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-event-source) which seems to be compatible with angular. To do so, run `npm install ng-event-source`. Then, in the code, use the `EventSourcePolyfill` object instead of `EventSource`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'ng-event-source';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    private eventSource: EventSourcePolyfill;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill('/subscribe', { heartbeatTimeout: 1000, connectionTimeout: 1000 });
    }

    // Rest of the code omitted for clarity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing an import

```
import * as EventSource from 'eventsource';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know this package, but it's look like it has nothing to do with Angular or Angular http module. Have you read the **browser polyfill** section in the documation ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource

I think this package is created for NodeJs but you can use it on browsser side but you need to add some extra files

Comment: I already used in an angular 4 project without any modifications. I only ran `npm install eventsource` and it was working perfectly